# sudo: grub2-mkconfig: command not found

Tags: command-line, grub2, virtualization

When I try perform the command "sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg", I get an error message stating "sudo: grub2-mkconfig: command not found". I am trying to perform single GPU passthrough by following this guide: https://youtu.be/3BxAaaRDEEw?t=354

Comment: Try using sudo grub-mkconfig instead

Comment: That seemed to have worked! Thank you!

Comment: @stripeyare please give Bernard an opportunity to update his answer and then mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo grub-mkconfig` instead.

[The difference between `grub-mkconfig` and `grub2-mkconfig` is explained here.](https://linuxhint.com/grub2_mkconfig_tutorial/)

> Even though GRUB 2 is installed on your computer, the **grub2-mkconfig** command may not be available in your favorite Linux distribution. But the **grub-mkconfig** command may be available in your Linux distribution. There is no difference between **grub-mkconfig** and **grub2-mkconfig** if GRUB 2 is installed.
>
> Note that, if you have GRUB legacy installed, then **grub-mkconfig** and **grub2-mkconfig** commands will not be the same.

Comment: What if both commands aren't working and showing the same error?

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from Bernard doesn't work then you may not have some packages installed. check if the following packages are installed otherwise install them:

```
sudo apt install grub2-efi grub2-efi-modules shim
```

for me ***grub2-efi*** package wasn't installed so installing that resolved the issue. This is for UEFI systems.